# How to intercept (see) all requests of a site written in React in WKWebView for iOS 13 and higher?

Tags: swift, wkwebview, apprequests, wknavigationdelegate, wkurlschemehandler

I can't intercept all requests, I tried to use WKNavigationDelegate, schemeHandler and some repositories, but nothing is working. Is there any way to get them?

Comment: WKWebView should be able to intercept all navigation events, but not "client-side" JS events within the page. The only way to intercept client-side events is to inject some JavaScript from native onto the page, and that injected code could report what you want back to native. Details depend on what those events you can't catch are, and what they do. For example if these events are messages, you could add your native listener to `webkit.messageHandlers` on JS side, and get them handled back to your WKScriptMessageHandler